# can somebody explain what data.match does with jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i just saw this used
if(data.match('success') != null)

and i looked online at the api but it just shows data im not sure what match does im guessing its normal javascript?

Comment: What api are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a string, the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method is usually used to retrieve the matches from a regular expression though it appears you can use a normal string parameter, in which case it will return that string in an array if it can be found, `null` otherwise.

Example

```
var foo = 'This is a string that has the word success in it';
foo.match('success'); // returns ["success"]
foo.match('foo'); // returns null
```